# Failing to update a Python Dictionary during Multiprocessing

Tags: python, dictionary, python-multiprocessing

I'm at a bit of a loss. My Python skills are a bit rusty, but I'm trying to process a Python Dictionary in parallel and updating the dictionary with a response.
The dictionary is defined currently in the script and will call a function that will take the "endpoint" and update with the "response".
Currently, within the multiprocessing function called, I can see the updated result when printing the dictionary, but it doesn't remain when calling the dictionary in the main function.

Where am I going wrong?

```
from multiprocessing import Manager, Pool
import time
from random import randint


# API function - For now, return random number
def APIResponse(x):
    print("Processing {}".format(x))
    randomInteger = randint(1, 10)
    time.sleep(randomInteger)
    print("Finished {}".format(x))
    
#    APIEndpoints[x]["response"] = str(randomInteger)
    APIEndpoints[x].update({"response": str(randomInteger)})
    # The below returns the correct updated dictionary
    print(APIEndpoints[x])

    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    APIEndpoints = {
        "basic": {
            "endpoint": "api_endpoint_basic",
            "response": ""
        },
        "address": {
            "endpoint": "api_endpoint_address",
            "response": ""
        },
        "age": {
            "endpoint": "api_endpoint_age",
            "response": ""
        },
        "salary": {
            "endpoint": "api_endpoint_salary",
            "response": ""
        }
    }
    
    # Set up the pools
    p = Pool(processes=len(APIEndpoints))
    # Process the pools in parallel
    p.map(APIResponse, APIEndpoints)

    # Print output of Dictionary
    print(APIEndpoints)
```

I'm expecting the `APIEndpoints` variable to have an updated `response` at the end of the script, but it is currently only showing an update withing the function `APIResponse`

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You may need to create four `manager.dict()`s inside `APIEndpoints`.